# Metric Convergence

Tags: convergence-divergence, metric-spaces

I'm trying to show that the sequence $a_n=n^2 +n$ converges or diverges with respect to the metric $d(x,y)=\vert \frac 1 x - \frac 1 y \vert$.

I know from just looking at it that it diverges but im unsure of how to show this using the metric space definition? Would anyone be able to clear this up for me please?

Comment: Converges *where*? What's your metric space?

Comment: here is the full question . Recall that a sequence a in a set M converges to L ∈ M with respect to the distance d on M, if for
every ǫ > 0 there is nǫ ∈ N so that for all n > nǫ we have d(a(n), L) < ǫ.
Let d be the distance on R(positive)= (0, ∞) given by
d(x, y) =|1/x -1/y|

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So your metric space is $X=\mathbb{R}^+$ with the distance $d(x,y)=\vert \frac 1 x - \frac 1 y \vert$.

Note that if the sequence $(a_n)_n$ is convergent to $L\in X$, with respect to $d$, then, as $n\to \infty$, 
$$d(a_n,L)= \left\vert \frac{1}{n^2+n} - \frac 1 L \right\vert\to 0.$$
What may we conclude?

Comment: here is the full question . Recall that a sequence a in a set M converges to L ∈ M with respect to the distance d on M, if for every ǫ > 0 there is nǫ ∈ N so that for all n > nǫ we have d(a(n), L) < ǫ. Let d be the distance on R(positive)= (0, ∞) given by d(x, y) =|1/x -1/y|

Comment: so then this means that the distance between them gets arbitrarily small and so a(n) converges ? is this because we have a certain distance function which means that a(n) converges when we use it ? because obviously the sequence a(n) would usually converge.

Comment: No, $a_n$ is not convergent in $X$.  Note that $\left\vert \frac{1}{n^2+n} - \frac 1 L \right\vert\to \left\vert\frac 1 L \right\vert$, and $\left\vert\frac 1 L \right\vert$ should be equal to zero.

Comment: but if |1/L|=0 , which it should be as L=infinity then why isn't it convergent on X , it would seem to me that 0=|1/L|<e    for e>0, which is what i thought the criteria for convergence in a metric space was ??

Comment: $\infty$ is not an element of the metric space $X$!

Comment: ohh, I see. this is the assumption ive been making that was messing everything up for me. thank you so much! so then my new answer should be .... a and L are element of M, M is an element of R+....Limd(a,L)=|1/L| ...L does not equal zero (obviously) or infinity( because L is supposed to be an element of M and infinity is not an element of M)...=>|1/L|>0...=> for all e>0, |1/L|>=e>0    which implies that a(n) is not convergent on X and hence is not a cauchy sequence

Comment: Yes, that's correct!

Comment: it was a long road but we did it Robert....Hoorah!!

Comment: thanks a million btw :):)

Comment: @jamiemma1995 I'm glad it helped.